# Log4j, meaning of Append = true / false

Tags: java, log4j

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append = true

The doc says:

> If the append parameter is true, the file will be appended to. Otherwise, the file designated by filename will be truncated before being opened.

Does it mean that if Append = true, new logs will be appended to the tail of the file? Then what does "truncated" indicate? Content will be deleted before the file being opened?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, "truncated" means "shortened" - in this case, it's basically that the file will be overwritten as if it never existed before.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon

Comment: @JonSkeet It's kind of trivial but that should be an answer, because it answered OP's question. It will never get an accepted answer otherwise, right?

Comment: @Fildor: I'm not sure it's a question that deserves an answer, really. I'll add that as an answer with a bit more elaboration, but it's more about English than coding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, "the file designated by filename will be truncated" means that any data that previously existed in the file will be gone. This is a more general concept than just logging.

Suppose you have a file initially containing the data "AB":

- If you open it to *append* the value "C", the file will end up containing "ABC".
- If you open it to *truncate* and then write "C", the file will end up containing "C".
- If you open it to overwrite without truncating, the file will end up containing "CB". (This is rarely a useful option.)